# Is it possible to list context property names of QQmlContext?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qqmlcontext

I am wondering if it's possible to get all context property names of specific `QQmlContext`.

So I can do something like:

```cpp
QQmlContext *ctx = ...;

for (auto contextPropertyName: ctx->getPropertyNames()) {
   qDebug() << contextPropertyName << ctx->contextProperty(contextPropertyName);
}
```

I achieved similar functionality for `QObject`'s with `obj->metaObject()->propertyCount()` and then `obj->metaObject()->property(i)`.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? The code you provided doesn't work?

Comment: There is no `getPropertyNames` method. :)

Comment: QQmlContext is derived from `QObject` so you can use qt meta system to loop through the properties ie. `QMetaObject::propertyCount` and `QMetaObject::property(int index)`.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. `ctx->property(...)` and `ctx->contextProperty(...)` return different things. Also for me`ctx->metaObject()->propertyCount()` always returns `0` because there is only 1 property `objectName`.

Comment: @elderapo Could you describe, what are you going to achieve by possible accessing to `getPropertyNames`? Isn't it [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Answer (score 2):

You can find your properties using `ctx->dynamicPropertyNames();`